# Is there a limit on email size?

Tags: email, protocol, network-protocols

Is there a limit in the protocols email uses in regards to the size of an email?
I am wondering about collective limits on body and attachments as well as individual limits on either attachment or body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size limit is not set by the IMAP or POP protocols but by the individual SMTP servers. And the limit is variable from server to server (you don't even have to specify a limit at all).